# UITabBar's tabBarItem color change in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I need to change the color of `UITabBarItem` into black.

My pic is like following pics.

Background Color is blue , so i want to change the gray `TabBarItem` into Black.

How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
UITabBarItem *addItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" image:nil tag:763];
[addItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_icon_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_icon_unselected.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see the docs [UITabBarItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In pre-iOS7, you can set custom images (won't be modified in any way by system) to the `UITabBarItem` using

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage
```

Above method is deprecated in iOS 7. On iOS 7 use one of these:

```
– initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *selectedImage
```

Comment: no bro. i don't mean for selected item. i means non-selected item.

Comment: `withFinishedUnselectedImage:`? That means unselected!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change background color blue to gray use this one,

```
tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

For TabBarItem into Black,

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   titleHighlightedColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```